# Create ASCX control for multiple actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to create a custom control that contains two radio buttons. I'm working with MVC4 & ASP.NET... I currently have two sets of two radio buttons in two different pages. On one page, the selection of a radio button opens a new tab and displays a certain page based on the selection; On the second page, the selection of a radio button calls a completely different page but shows it within the current page.

My Code:

```
<input onchange="enableOption1()" type="radio" />
<%:Resources.Global.Option1_Description %>
<br />
<input onchange="enableOption2()" type="radio" />
<%:Resources.Global.Option2_Description %>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function enableOption1()
   {...}
   function enableOption2()
   {...}
</script>
```

each function is different for the two pages, is there a way to create an `*.ascx` page that can take in different parameters to some how reuse the same control of 2 radio buttons?

Comment: You can create ascx controller and set properties to do different functionalities and populate those properties from your aspx page when calling the controller

Comment: what does that look like in code? how do i pass in those properties in the calling aspx pages?

Answer (score 2):

So in your case, create 2 properties in user control:

```
public bool OpenInTab { get; set; }
public string URL { get; set; }
```

In your aspx page when you init your user control you will now have access to these two properties, so on the page that needs to open in new tab, pass `OpenInTab` property as `true` e.g.

```
<uc1:myusercontrol ID="myucl" runat="server" OpenInTab="true" URL="http://google.com" />
```

Then in your user control based on the property open the `URL` in new tab if it `OpenInTab` is set to `true`.